# How to interpret a transformed linear regression model

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear, back-transformation

I'm playing with the [trafo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trafo/vignettes/vignette_trafo.pdf) R-package and this small [data](https://daviddalpiaz.github.io/appliedstats/data/initech.csv). After using the `assumptions` function, I found the log shift opt transformation is the best for normalizing the residues of my linear regression model, then:

```r
    library("trafo")
    initech = read.csv("initech.csv")
    initech.lm<- lm(salary~years,data=initech)
    initech.log <- trafo_lm(object = initech.lm, 
                     trafo = "logshiftopt")
    summary(initech.log)
```

I had the output:

```r
    Call:
    lm(formula = salary ~ years, data = initech)
    
    Residuals:
       Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
    -57225 -18104    241  15589  91332 
    
    Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)     5302       5750   0.922    0.359    
    years           8637        389  22.200   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 27360 on 98 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.8341,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8324 
    F-statistic: 492.8 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
    
    
    Summary of transformed model:  logshiftopt transformation 
    
    Formula in call:  salaryt ~ years 
    
    Call:
    lm(formula = formula, data = data)
    
    Residuals:
         Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -0.51268 -0.12338  0.02235  0.13425  0.38458 
    
    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) 10.608104   0.038459  275.83   <2e-16 ***
    years        0.074236   0.002602   28.53   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 0.183 on 98 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.8925,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8914 
    F-statistic: 813.9 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

In order to interpret the data using my transformed linear regression model I need to have my new coefficients after the transformations back to the old scale, how can I do that? These estimates $10.608104$ and $0.074236$ are hard to interpret.

I'm thinking to use the inverse of the log shift opt transformation in these estimates, but it's very risky and tiresome. Are there some function in R in this package or in another one that can help me with that?

Comment: The new coefficients are the same as printed here.  What's missing is the estimated value of the offset $\lambda.$  You will need to extract this from the object returned by `trafo_lm`.  Regardless, there's no simple interpretation.  For that purpose people usually do not accept automatically generated transformations but instead select an interpretable transformation that will work well. For your data it's likely $\lambda$ is inconsequentially small; in that case, re-run the model using the logarithm (that is, set $\lambda=0$) and proceed accordingly.  (Logs are easy to interpret.)

Comment: @whuber Yes, but I want to get the new coefficients but with the old scale. Let me give you an example. Suppose I use the $log_{10}$ transformation and get the new coefficients as 10 and 100, then in order to interpret the new coefficients I turn back to the last scale getting the inverse of the log, i.e. the exponential, than my new coefficients are 1 and 2.

Comment: That is incorrect: you cannot back-transform the coefficients to produce a model for the original response.  That would violate the rules of logarithms (and arithmetic generally).

Comment: @whuber That's true, when I wrote down the equations I realized I couldn't. Thank you very much